# R get linear regression equation for boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, boxplot, ggpmisc

I didn´t found a sufficient answer in this forum yet, so I decided to raise my own question.

I want to get the linear regression equation of a linear fit from a boxplot. I have this data:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                               5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                               5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                               6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                               6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
y = c(169, 79.5, 78.5, 75, 99.5, 68, 14, 30.5, 107.5, 51, 
      43, 33, 21.5, 35, 11, 1, 38, 54.5, 26.5, 143, 158, 171, 31.5, 
      67.5, 1, 57.5, 12, 36.5, 1, 23.5, 22.5, 71, 141, 218, 7.5, 
      1, 129, 144.5, 76, 46.5, 75.5, 45, 12, 24, 67, 65.5, 44.5, 
      37.5, 25.5, 19, 15, 1, 17.5, 50, 22.5, 90, 226, 220, 32, 
      69.5, 1, 79.5, 7, 44, 1, 15.5, 22, 75.5, 178, 153, 4.5, 1, 
      159, 89, 57, 71, 98.5, 47.5, 18.5, 30, 119, 57.5, 41, 33.5, 
      30, 31, 10, 1, 12, 43.5, 20.5, 98, 146.5, 145, 34, 64.5, 
      1, 40.5, 17, 41, 1, 14.5, 16.5, 71, 181, 168, 2, 1, 159, 
      103, 69, 65.5, 97.5, 37.5, 21, 15.5, 120.5, 46, 27, 29.5, 
      16.5, 20, 7.5, 1, 15.5, 42.5, 21.5, 111, 102.5, 124, 20.5, 
      51.5, 1, 22.5, 15, 42, 1, 13, 13.5, 64.5, 138, 155, 4.9, 
      1, 190, 89.5, 74.5, 79, 78, 59.5, 19.5, 21, 88.5, 44, 18, 
      19, 10, 13, 4, 1, 9.5, 44, 17, 140.5, 98, 112.5, 29.5, 62.56, 
      1, 31, 11.5, 49.5, 1, 10, 8.5, 40.5, 121, 141, 2.5, 1, 170, 
      87.5, 92, 77, 65, 34, 8, 26, 98, 51.5, 26, 19, 9, 8.5, 7.5, 
      1, 4.5, 0, 15.5, 80, 69, 59, 28, 44.5, 1, 38.5, 10, 51.5, 
      1, 3, 5, 65, 107, 152, 5, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -216L), class = "data.frame")
  

p <- ggplot(data = data) + 
  aes(x = x,
      y = y) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + geom_jitter(shape = 1, position = position_jitter(0.1)) +
  ylim(0, NA) + 
  theme_light() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = TRUE, formula = y ~ x, aes(group = 1)) 
print(p)


fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = data)
fit
```

which results in this output:
[image]

1. How can I extract the regression equation for this dataset? The function `fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = data)`  just gives me one intercept and 5 coefficients, which is not my desired output. I want a simple regression equation in the form of `y = a + bx`.
2. How can I put this equation into the diagramm? I´ve already looked into `ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq()`, but this doesn´t seem to work with boxplot linear regression.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Your `data$x` is a factor, hence R uses dummy-variables in the linear model. But you want to see `data$x` as a numeric, hence use `data$x <- as.numeric(data$x)` before calling the linear model `lm(y ~ x, data = data)` and you will get the intercept (66.138) and one coefficient for x (-3.809).

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn´t thought this would be so easy..:-)

I tried to add the regression equation now to the plot with  `ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE)`, but I can´t get it done. Any recommendations for this?

Comment: You are trying to fight against one of the limitations that ggplot2 has by design. Within a single plot, a given aesthetics can be assigned only one scale. So the x aesthetic can be either a continuous variable or a discrete variable (= factor), but not both in the same ggplot. There is a reason for this as a data variable cannot be considered both as discrete or continuous, or at the very least doing so makes things confusing. In your case most clearly by the use of jitter as along the x axis the observations are not longer at the original location, the location relevant for the regression.

Comment: From the statistics point of view, is it is obvious that the distribution is skewed. If this is what you are trying to show, then you could use `stat_summary()` to add means and standard deviations per group.

Comment: Quantiles are the continuous generalisation of a boxplot (for a discrete x axis). You may like to look at this answer to a quantile question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65948506/4927395